How do I know I am preparing a superposition with a given relative phase?
On the ordinary view that quantum states form a vector space, any two states straightforwardly have a sum.
But, after noticing that global phase is irrelevant, many writers speak instead of a projective vector space, in which the action of $\mathbb{C}$ has been quotiented. Now there is no longer any additive law. How do we speak of superpositions? Of a state being a superposition of two or more other states?
We could define a plurality of additive laws, one for each real number $\theta$, where the $\theta$-sum of two rays $[v]$ and $[w]$ is $[v+e^{i\theta}w]$ (braces denoting the quotient cosets). But now I cannot straightforwardly sum two states; I require, as input, a third quantity --- the relative phase --- which is not determined by the two states to be summed.
Can someone tell me, concretely, in experimental situations, but as generally as possible, how I know that some process or preparation has produced a superposition of two states and how I know what $\theta$ was involved?
In the case of the double slit experiment, I suppose $\theta$ is determined according to the pathlength-difference. Using the path integral, maybe we can always put $\theta$ down to certain action integrals along paths. Is it that simple?
If I want to produce a particular superposition of two given states with a chosen $\theta$, how do I do it?

Are you okay with how such states are prepared in classical systems? Eg polarization of an electric field?

Honestly I'm not sure how you'd prepare a particular electric field, outside of preparing the charge and current source. i.e., wires and things should be represented as a J thats supported on a narrow cylinder, then E follows from Maxwell with E(infty)=0 b.c.s

Sorry, its not clear yet what you're getting at.

If I might clarify my question: it seems to me the expanation cannot be "do whatever preparation was involved in V, and similtaneously whatever preparation was involved in U" since preparing V is the same as preparing -V, yet preparing V+U is not the same as preparing V-U.

Honestly the double slit experiment is just breeding more confusion. Frequently the phase different is put down to a pathlength difference, but why are we talking about classical paths for classical point-electrons, anyways? And why straight line paths? What if the electron did a loop de loop? In truth, I guess, you could just write down the Hamiltonian (free aside from an infinite, slitted barrier) and do Schroedinger evolution. Then we evade talking about superposition or phases altogether: we just get a resulting wavefunction and compute its inner product on various position eigenstates.

Electric fields can be complex superpositions of different components, even classically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization#Mathematical_description. So sending light through polarized sunglasses can prepare a superposition of horizontally and vertically polarized light with a particular relative phase in the superposition, even classically

Double slit experiment is classical electromagnetism and wave interference, that's why I asked about classical systems. The propagation due to Maxwell's equations gives the complex exponentials, even though yes light propagates as a wave in that theory and not just in a straight line. The funny quantum part about the double slit experiment, doing it one particle at a time, can only really come after you're okay with classical wave interference

To be specific to this question: there is probably a specific preparation for each specific superposition. Perhaps there is a preparation for one specific superposition and then another operation you can do to alter the relative phase. But I agree that you can't just "do a superposition of the two preparation procedures" without you yourself being in a quantum superposition (hand wavingly)

Not sure I understand the analogy. My issue concerns the guage present in a vector-space description of quantum states. Are these E and B fields also have any gauge?

The point is it's not an analogy: relative phases are physically meaningful, are not unique to quantum theory, and each individual relative phase may be unique to a specific preparation that is in no way a superposition of two other preparations. Moreover, an existing relative phase can be modified by another physical operation.

I.e., life doesn't just give you two states and tell you to superpose them. Life gives you a specific preparation procedure that leads to a specific preparation. That might involve some relative-phase reference (this is part of an old debate https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.55.3195, https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0507214)
